# clang: error: no such file or directory error

Tags: c

When I compiling my project, compiler threw this message:

```
if ( . != "." ) /bin/mv math3dgraphics.o . 

ar rcv ./mathtools.a ./mathtools.o ./matrix.o ./matrixtools.o ./pscmds.o ./pccurvecmds.o ./math3dgraphics.o
r - ./mathtools.o
r - ./matrix.o
r - ./matrixtools.o
r - ./pscmds.o
r - ./pccurvecmds.o
r - ./math3dgraphics.o
ranlib ./mathtools.a
/usr/bin/gcc -g -o -I/opt/X11/include xrna xrna.o xrnainit.o xrnatools.o xrnadisplay.o xrnamenu.o xrnalabels.o xrnalw.o xrnasstr.o xrnapccurve.o xrnatube.o xrnassymbols.o xrnatstr.o xrnabasepair.o xrnacon.o xrnathred.o xrnacolorwidget.o xrnastred.o xrnainquire.o tdhrefnuc.o xrnabuttonmenu.o grplinebuttonlist.o grplinefnclist.o grpparallelogrambuttonlist.o grpparallelogramfnclist.o grptextbuttonlist.o grptextfnclist.o grptrianglebuttonlist.o grptrianglefnclist.o grparcbuttonlist.o grparcfnclist.o grparrowbuttonlist.o grparrowfnclist.o transformbuttonlist.o transformfnclist.o xrnaprintbuttonlist.o xrnaprintfnclist.o xrnagraphics.o xrnaneutronmap.o xrnaalign.o helixtools.o helixio.o helixarc.o ./botif.a ./mathtools.a -DMATHHFILE='"./mathtools.h"' -L/opt/X11/lib -lX11 -lm -lg -lc -I/opt/X11/include
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'xrna'

make[1]: *** [install] Error 1

make: *** [xrna] Error 2
```

What get me confused is that xrna is the executable file supposed to be generated, but why compiler say it's missing?

Comment: Try replacing the `-I/opt/X11/include` and `xrna`, i.e. `/usr/bin/gcc -g -o xrna -I/opt/X11/include  xrna.o ...`.

Comment: The `-o` option is immediately followed by the output file name; you chose to have the output go to `-I/opt/X11/include` (which is pretty eccentric as a file name), and you said that one of the files it should work with (as an input) is called `xrna`.  If you'd already compiled the program, you'd have a different error, but the command line would be just as wrong.  You need `-o xrna -I/opt/X11/include` or `-I/opt/X11/include -o xrna` or some other variant.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `-o` option in a link statement, the very next entry has to be the name of the file to output, NOT some library option.